# Is BertTokenizer similar to word embedding?

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, word-embedding, huggingface-tokenizers

The idea of using BertTokenizer from huggingface really confuses me.

1. When I use

   ```
   tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased")
   tokenizer.encode_plus("Hello")
   ```

Does the result is somewhat similar to when I pass
a one-hot vector representing "Hello" to a learning embedding matrix?

2. How is

   ```
   BertTokenizer.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased")
   ```

different from

```
BertTokenizer.from_pretrained("bert-**large**-uncased")
```

and other pretrained?

Answer (score 0):

The `encode_plus` and `encode` functions tokenize your texts and prepare them in a proper input format of the BERT model. Therefore you can see them similar to the one-hot vector in your provided example.
The [`encode_plus`](https://huggingface.co/transformers/internal/tokenization_utils.html#transformers.tokenization_utils_base.PreTrainedTokenizerBase.encode_plus) returns a BatchEncoding consisting of [`input_ids`](https://huggingface.co/transformers/glossary.html#input-ids), [`token_type_ids`](https://huggingface.co/transformers/glossary.html#token-type-ids), and [`attention_mask`](https://huggingface.co/transformers/glossary.html#attention-mask).

The pre-trained model differs based on the number of encoder layers. The *base* model has 12 encoders, and the *large* model has 24 layers of encoders.